# Cannot connect to wifi using wicd-curses

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, ethernet, wicd-curses

I have just recently purchased a raspberry pi 2 the GUI interface is very different from my other raspberry pi b+

i have successfully connected my other raspberry pi to the internet using the recommended wifi dongle and wicd-curses using this tutorial https://blog.bartbania.com/raspberry_pi/easy-wireless-configuration-for-raspberry-pi/

but i cannot seem to connect the raspberry pi 2 to the internet wicd-curses says it is trying to connect i have double checked the spelling for the WPA and the raspberry pi is in the same room as the router too. And it says NOT Connected

i am using the pihut wifi dongle my wireless network and others are found but no connection i have rebooted it and tried to start it and stop wicd-curses. Also i have reinstalled wheezy raspbian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have recently purchased a raspberry pi 2 and installed Raspbian it probably has a different WiFi setup using `dhcpcd`. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/another-raspbian-desktop-user-interface-update/

Forget any older tutorials and just use the new GUI WiFi setup. These can be made to work, but require manual configuration.

Comment: following this tutorial no wifi networks are found and i get an icon with 2 pcs nothing else

Comment: Thanks works cant upvote lack of reputation but this works fine